# relations between assembly and project in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assemblies

I'm a bit confused. 
Looking at some existing code here at my university, I see that a project is always somehow related to a single assembly. I'm new in c# and I read a bit about assemblies and modules but I didn't find anything about the relation between the "project" logical unit and the "assembly" logical unit, and I wondered if this is a convention, and if I can somehow control this from VS.

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the standard build model for Visual Studio.  One project normally produces one assembly.  One solution can contain more than one project.  There is no direct support for creating modules, you'll have to do that by hand so you can run csc.exe with the /target:module option.  There are very few scenarios where that makes sense.